# Shipping rules for group of countries (ex. UK or ITALY)

Tags: rules, commerce

I'm creating the shipping rates depending on country. I've got groups of countries with the same rate.

I've installed Shipping 2.0 and Flat Rate module.

I've limited the available countries through the customer profile and then I've created the flat rates for group of country (ITALY or BRAZIL) and some for a single country (UK).

In the components I did this

Condition:
Order address component comparision

Address : Shipping address

Address component : Country

VALUE : GB

(REMEMBER, THE VALUE IS THE TWO LETTER ABBREVIATION, ITALY WILL BE IT AND UNITED KINGDOM IS GB. YOU CAN FIND IT LOOKING A THE HTML OF THE SHIPPING FORM)

I've added one condition per each country of that group. I've implemented with OR but for some reason it does not work.

This is the result:
Condition 1 : IT

OR

Condition 2: FR

This does not work, so I tried:

Condition 1: IT

--OR

----Condition 2: FR

But nothing...

What Am I doing wrong? It's something related to the "OR"?

The flat rate with single country works, the one with complex rules doesn't.

---

I SOLVED IT: IT WAS THE CONDITIONS POSITIONS. THE RIGHT WAY TO USE "OR" IS THIS:

OR

--CONTITION 1

--CONTIDION 2

HERE YOU CAN FIN A REALLE NICE [RULES TUTORIAL](http://drupalize.me/videos/combining-conditions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OR and AND-groups takes all conditions inside of them with the chosen operator.

Your:

Condition 1: IT
--OR
----Condition 2: FR

Will be converted into ([Condition 1] AND ([Condition 2])).

Try putting both **Condition 1** and **Condition 2** in the OR-group:

--OR
----Condition 1: IT
----Condition 2: FR

This should be converted into ([Condition 1] OR [Condition 2]).
If that's what you're after.

*Edit: Just a couple of minutes too late :)*

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to **exclude** a shipping rate for certain countries and had no luck with the examples above.

But this one works:

--NOT Country A
--OR
----NOT Country B
--OR
----NOT Country C

Comment: You would actually not need the OR-groups in your example above which is the same as: (NOT Country A) AND (NOT Country B) AND (NOT Country C).